# Hostile creatures causing work cancellations?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have some moose men and women running around inside my fortress, and any dwarf that bumps into them will cancel their work.  But they don't seem to be attacking my dwarves.  I also wonder if they are eating my food stocks, cause one is hanging out at my stockpile.

What can I do about them?

I have some war dogs but not sure how to tell them to attack, nor sure if I will suffer bad consequences if I do.

Edit: Nevermind, just randomly struck down my dwarf.  Apparently he didn't even put up a fight :(

Edit2: Ah, combat doesn't show up in announcements, but instead in reports.  Apparently there has been quite a bit of fighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moose Men and Women, like their Moose kith, are dangerous due to their size, but won't go out of their way to get your dwarves, either. (Unlike the evil, evil Honey Badger)

This is a very literal case of "they're just as afraid of your dwarves as your dwarves are of them".

However, it sounds like your dwarves may have accidentally cornered a Moose Man or several, and, like all cornered creatures, will defend itself vociferously. Since you have several dead dwarves on hand, it's likely that they simply wandered too close for their own good.

Comment: Exactly what happened.  Only one dwarf died in all the "unnoticed" fighting, and that case he was trying to go down a onewide corridor that the moose woman was in and had no where else to go.  I did notice she usually stayed away from my dwarves.  After a little poking around in menus I managed to assemble the 6 remaining dwarves into a tattered militia and had them beat the moose woman to death with their bare hands...

Answer (score 3):

Moose men are dangerous, and often breed with bat men, with dangerous results:

[image]

Wipe them out as soon as possible.

**Edit:**

As some have pointed out; this answer needs a more serious part to it:

Creatures will generally only cause job cancellations if they pose some manner of danger to your dwarves. If any animal in your fortress is causing job cancellations, dispatch the militia to kill it, even if just to stay on the safe side.

Comment: This isn't an answer... but you can't embed pictures in comments... but... batmooseman.

Comment: @Raven: Answer updated to be an actual answer. Congratulations, you ruined a perfectly good joke. Happy now? (Also, good call, actually answering questions is kind of important.)

Comment: I will point out, however, that Raccoons will cause the same job cancellation spam as dragons. Dwarves are completely and utter cowards.

Comment: @Raven: And you should be as diligent in killing raccoons as in killing dragons. My point stands.

Comment: @Raven: Also; raccoons? Surely you mean badgers.

Comment: No, I mean Raccoons. Raccoons are actually worse in some ways, since they'll repeatedly run *towards* dwarves, in an attempt to get their grubby little hands on your stockpiles. At least badgers just cut with the flirtations entirely and go straight for the bloody, bloody kill.

Comment: @Raven This reminds me of one night I was fixing a porch light in the dark and a smallish young raccoon kept coming up and tapping on my shoe while I wasn't looking.  Curious little fellow.  I think he wanted to eat me.